# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. change driver/executor memory without spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, garbage-collection

I am trying to read a 8mb excel file,
i am getting this error.

i use intellij with spark 2.4.4
scala 2.12.12
and jdk 1.8

this is my code : -

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
.set("spark.driver.memory","4g")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
// .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")



val spark = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("trimTest")
.master("local[*]")
.config(conf)
.getOrCreate()

 

val df = spark.read
.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
option("header", "true").
load("data/12file.xlsx")
```

Now, these are my spark ui screenshots,
can you tell me what is the main issue and how can i increase the job executor memory.
[image]
[image]
stack :-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.Class.newReflectionData(Class.java:2511)
at java.lang.Class.reflectionData(Class.java:2503)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2660)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:403)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:53)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:276)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:206)
at javax.management.StandardMBean.getAttribute(StandardMBean.java:372)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$GetHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:122)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:167)
at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getMemoryUsed(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MBeanExecutorMetricType.getMetricValue(ExecutorMetricType.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.SingleValueExecutorMetricType.getMetricValues(ExecutorMetricType.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.SingleValueExecutorMetricType.getMetricValues$(ExecutorMetricType.scala:44)
at org.apache.spark.metrics.MBeanExecutorMetricType.getMetricValues(ExecutorMetricType.scala:60)
```

Comment: You can read more about `GC overhead limit exceeded` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html). The solution Oracle provide is to increase the heap size.

Comment: i read that, what i got was to increase my driver memory but i can't find a clear way to increase my memory locally on intellij at runtime.

Comment: How are you running? .. From your local

Comment: yes i am running it locally with a build.sbt in intellij.